# Cannot make Imagick detect supported format on Windows + PHP 5.6 (Xampp)

Tags: php, windows, apache, dll, imagick

its been 3 days of research, google and frustration to make imagick work on my XAMPP box. I can get as far on making it as php module. But it cannot detect supported formats.
[image]

As you can see, I currently have 3.1.2 installed, but I actually worked all the way from the most recent 3.4.1 and jumping from those releases tagged with `stable` but I just can't make it work.

When I try to run:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen('http://xxxxx.png', 'rb');
$img = new Imagick();
$img->readImageFile($handle);
$img->thumbnailImage(100, 0);
echo $image;
```

I am getting:

```
Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Unable to read image from the filehandle' in xxxxx:5 Stack trace: #0 xxxxx\index.php(5): Imagick->readimagefile(Resource id #3) #1 {main} thrown in xxxxx\index.php on line 5
```

What I have is:

```
Windows 8.1 64-bit
PHP 5.6.12, x86, TS
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xold.png)

This is what I actually have done so far, in terms of installing it:

- Download any `-Thread Safe (TS) x86` package from
  https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick
- Extract the .zip (1) `php_imagick.dll` to `C:\_XAMPP\php\ext` (2)
  Extract `CORE_RL_*` files to `C:\_xampp\apache\bin`
- Download `ImageMagick-7.0.1-1-Q16-x86-dll.exe` from
  [Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)
- Installed it at `C:\ImageMagick`
- Add MAGICK_HOME to environment PATH. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV5fp.png
- All `*_.dll` file in `C:\ImageMagick\modules\coders` copy to
  `C:\_Xampp\apache\bin`
- All `*_.dll` file in `C:\ImageMagick\modules\coders` copy to
  `C:\ImageMagick\`
- Restart Apache via Xampp

And still can't make my PHP detect Imagick supported file formats even though they should be http://prntscr.com/b1l54u :((

Can somebody tell me what did I miss? Please?

Comment: Did you resolve this? I've got the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be going a bit of a convoluted route.

The method I used to install it when I had it running was:

1. Download and install Ghostscript with an exe file
2. Download and install imagemagick with an exe file - make sure you let it add the path to the environmental variables. You may not need this step but I wanted to use Imagemagick I'm my website and on my computer anyway.
3. Download the Imagick dll file and put it in the recommended folder - I can not remember which now.
4. Uncomment the Imagick option in the php.ini file. I had
   two or three php.ini files on my system and I did it in each one.
5. Turned off the computer and restarted. Started XAMPP and it worked.

This only worked for a couple of installs and when I upgraded the operating system I could not get it to work due to incompatible versions of php and the Imagick.dll. If I should ever want to use Imagick I would do it on my server as the hosts installed it there for me.
You can still write your code locally and test it on your production server. It is a bit of a pain but would probably be quicker/easier than trying to get Imagick working on your PC.

Out of interest I gave up with it and use Imagemagick with exec() and the command line.

Comment: sorry, just confused, this Ghostscript? http://ghostscript.com/ i installed it, but seems like it is just a command line? what is it supposed to do? If I understand your guide correctly, i have done the same thing as your guide except that I should also install Ghostscript? I did it but other formats are still not detected. Thanks!

Comment: That is strange @TheWolf as every time I have installed Imagick it worked straight away until I could not find the correct dll file. At the time the guy who supplied the dll files stopped doing it. Ghostscript is a pdf program and is needed for Imagemagick to work with pdf files. Reading your post again what happens if you try a local file and used one of the simple examples from the php site: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php